How to load values from a SOPS file into a Java Spring Boot application
I have a Java 21 Spring Boot 3.2 application that needs to load a bunch of properties. In the application, several files use:
@Value("${some.value}")
private String someValue;

I also have a SOPS file containing several key/values that I need the Spring Boot app to be able to load. The file contents are in the following format:
some.value = myValue

How do I get the values loaded into the Spring Boot app?
This is for local development. Right now the values are being copied into an application-local.properties file for local development. But then that file needs to be deleted after because having the two files is pointless and the SOPS file is encrypted. Is there a way to just load the values into the environment?
Thanks.

I am curious to learn about the sops file; what's the extension of the file?

@SibinMuhammed the sops file extension is .properties

I solved this by making a class which implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> and invoking it only when the local spring profile is active by creating an application-local.properties which I have added to my .gitignore which minimally contains: context.initializer.classes=com.your.path.to.class.
In the initialize method I create a ProcessBuilder with a command to authenticate && decrypt the sops file to stdout. I capture & parse the output into a MapPropertySource which fits the applicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(props)
Adding last allows you to override any properties found in sops via your ignored local properties file. Additionally, this method allows properties from sops to be a source for @Value annotations unlike many other means of doing this.
The part that sucks is having to write the code which parses your decrypted .properties file. Consider things like comments # and !, multiline support, and handling special characters like \n as non-literal.
I did see a git repo called mrvisser/prop-doc which might do this for you?
